# iOS app automation test with AWS Device Farm and Appium

Tags: ios, react-native, appium, aws-device-farm

I would like to use AWS Device Farm for automation test with Appium, and I passed the test with Appium on local, but after I use the same test to AWS Device Farm, the test failed.

The test result shows: "An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters". 
That is, it can't get the specific element(a button on webView) I want to click. But it's weird because the test passed with the local test.

Does anyone has the same situation with that? I use React Native to develop the app, but I think it's not the reason I got the fail result.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please share your run url so that we can pull your logs to check what is going wrong.
For getting the run url, login to Device Farm console . Click on the run where you are seeing this problem. Copy paste the url from the browser.

Sample Run url looks like this
https://us-west-2.console.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/home?region=us-west-2#/projects/61a601c1-6142-4e9e-beb0-de5618ae3c63/runs/20378f21-5502-4977-bd4c-69c3491ef7d7

Also a couple of questions
1) Are you seeing this issue on all devices or a single device
2) Do you look at the video of the test run? One common case where this can occur is because of system pop ups.

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry for late.
The url is [here](https://us-west-2.console.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/home?region=us-west-2#/projects/5a29ea1b-01a1-40eb-9dae-d1a19cee5847/runs/53c81a62-3116-4bf9-95ae-544c6f68f040).

And below is my answers for questions:
1) I passed the test on my side for real device and some simulators. The test result were fail when I use AWS Device Farm for iOS9.X; and for iOS10.X, it always keep waiting and not launch my app.

2) I checked the result video and  make sure it always got fail result when the progress is in webView.